# Combustion of halo-organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, combustion

My question is based on the [Preparatory Problem Set](http://icho2015.msu.az/uploads/files/Preparatory_problems_IChO_2015_May_1.pdf) for the 47th IChO Problem 26 - Holy War against Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse (it is on page 36). It is written that cooling of Y combustion products from 150 to 0 degrees Celsius does not result in any condensed phase, and addition of silver chloride to the supernatant of this combustion product provide some precipitate, so I concluded that this organic compound have either (or both) chloride and bromide, since iodine is too large for this substance. After calculating some possible answers, I've concluded that compound Y is $\ce{C3H2BrClO2}$.

My question is, if I combust compound Y ($\ce{C3H2BrClO2}$), will I get some products that aren't condensed when I cool these combustion products?

Comment: I'm surprised that you don't get any water formed. Most organics give some water on combustion.